# NServiceBus Thread Management

Tags: multithreading, nservicebus

NServiceBus re-utilizes Threads as in:
http://andreasohlund.net/2010/03/25/thread-static-caching-in-nservicebus/

How is this optimization done? One Thread per physical message? One Thread per logical message? Any other criteria?

Has the problem in the link been solved in NServiceBus 4.6.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that problem has been addressed in later versions.
The fix was to introduce child containers, see http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/nservicebus-support-for-child-containers